# USB cordless mouse stopped working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04, usb, mouse

Two days ago my cordless USB mouse stopped working.

It works fine with other computers. The battery is ok and well connected.

I only noticed it stopped working yesterday, and don't know why it's happened. I can only imagine it was because of some updates running the day before.

Comment: Is it Bluetooth or one of those mini dongles? If the latter, try putting it in a different USB port?

Comment: It's onde of those mini dongles, tryied another usb port and still not working.
I also have a wireless keyboard and it works fine on every usb port, so no usb issues.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up formating my pc back to ubuntu 20.04 and it works fine, didn't understand what happened though

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I resolved this by uninstalling usbguard package. Might help. Make sure you reboot after removing usbguard package.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is no documentation for what I suggested, I figured it out via hit & trial & it worked.