# ubuntu 22.04 wireless mouse disappeared

Tags: 22.04, mouse

Using xubuntu without problems till now. I turned on my computer today and realized my wireless mouse is not working. It ran correctly earlier and doesn't work now. Of course I've checked available topics but that didn't help any.

The problem looks similar to [this][1] one but the only one answer does not work for me.

Of course I've checked usb devices (lsusb):

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:6202 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. C-Media(R) Audio
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13d3:5467 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:3557 IMC Networks Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My USB wireless mouse is not detected. Google didn't help.

Can anybody help?

Regards,
z
[1]: [USB cordless mouse stopped working on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438461/usb-cordless-mouse-stopped-working-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Comment: Of course you have replaced the mouse batteries.

Comment: Might be a powersaving issue. Try `sudo rmmod usbmouse; sudo modprobe usbmouse` to unload and reload the driver (eventually repeat with usbhid instead of usbmouse). Unplugging and replugging the dongle might help too, but I guess you tried that already.

Answer (score 1):

Lets get the common issues out of the way.

- What brand is it? Do they have linux drivers or firmware update? A recent update/upgrade could have caused this issue.
- Is it bluetooth?
- Rechargeable or used alkaline batteries? Stick with alkaline until you can verify its working.
- Are you using rechargeable NiMH AA or AAA batteries? Chargerrcould say charged but device doesn't like its low battery voltage/amperage output.
- Can you verify USB dongle still works on another PC? Visibly inspect dongle USB connection for damage and try back of PC USB 2.0 connections. USB3 can cause issues.
- Did someone put tape on the bottom of the mouse LED? Fav office prank
- Boot into a different kernel and see if it was caused by a recent kernel upgrade.
- Boot into a LIVE USB OS and see if it works.

Let us know what worked, if anything.

Comment: I've tried under another kernel - caused some irreparable failure. That's why I have to reinstall now. But on live usb I have the mouse again.